# Pushing Left Arrow Key on Radio Button Goes Right on HTML RTL mode

Tags: html, browser, radio-button, right-to-left

I'm running the code below on chrome and iexplorer, focusing on the radio buttons and navigating via Left/Right arrow buttons.

On chrome, the buttons are focused as expected (Left-Arrow goes to the left button etc.)
But on IE11 **the arrows go the reverse direction** (Left-Arrow goes right and Right-Arrow goes left)

Is there any way to override this that both browsers work as expected on RTL?

```
<body dir="rtl">
    <form>
    <div style="direction:rtl">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> 1
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> 2
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> 3  
    </div>
    </form> 
</body>
```